# I'm unable to catch errors from an async functio

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Given the following function to update values from the backend:

```js
const updateValues = async (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.patch(
      ...
    );
    ...
    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.response);
    return {};
  }
};
```

I'm have not been able to successfully react to the Promise function, here is my implementation:

```js
const response = updateValues('bar', id, value1, value2, 'foo'
);
response
  .then(() => console.log('success:', response))
  .catch((err) => console.log('fail:', err));
```

What I'm getting is that regardless `response` always resolve and I never get to catch an error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: But your entire function body is inside a `try`/`catch`, and all the `catch` does is return normally?

Comment: The problem is that your `updateValues` function never throws. It always catches any axios errors and returns an empty object instead.

Comment: You could replace `return {};` with `throw err;` to rethrow the error. See: https://jsfiddle.net/04jnzo5d/

Comment: What about not using a try/catch when using then/catch?

Comment: I have no control over the backend code, so I guess there is not much I can do in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to decide where you want to catch the error that's being thrown. Currently you're catching the error inside of the `updateValues` function.

If you want to handle an error thrown by Axios you could write the function this way:

```js
const updateValues = async (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
  const response = await axios.patch(...); // If Axios throws an error will propagate up to the caller
  ...
  // You could also throw other errors here manually if you'd like
  return response.data;
};
```

Then you can handle the error at the call site:

```js
updateValues('bar', id, value1, value2, 'foo')
  .then((data) => console.log('success:', data))
  .catch((err) => console.log('fail:', err)); // Thrown exception handled here.
```

If you'd like to learn more: [Here's a good article on JS exceptions & best practices.](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-exceptions-best-practices-for-synchronous-and-asynchronous-environments-39f66b59f012)